# On reaction change variable from another async function

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am working on a discord bot for creating polls, my code is here:

```
@bot.command(name="newpoll")
async def new_poll(ctx, question, *options):
    if len(options) > 12:
        await ctx.send("You can have a maximum of 12 choices in your poll")

    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "Poll",
                              description = question,
                              colour = discord.Colour.red())

        fields = [("Options", "\n".join([f"{emotes[idx]} {option}" for idx, option in enumerate(options)]), False),
                  ("Instructions", "Please react in order to vote!", False)]

        for name, value, inline in fields:
            embed.add_field(name = name, value = value, inline = inline)

        embed = embed.add_field(name = "Total votes", value = 0, inline = False)
        message = await ctx.send(embed = embed)

        for emoji in emotes[:len(options)]:
            await message.add_reaction(emoji)

        message_win = await bot.get_channel(message.channel.id).fetch_message(message.id)
        total_votes = sum(reaction.count for reaction in message_win.reactions) - len(options)

        tv_embed = embed.set_field_at(2, name = "Total votes", value = total_votes, inline = False)
        await message.edit(embed = tv_embed)
```

The total vote count is stored in the `total_votes` variable which I plan to display by editing the embed message like in the last two lines. I want that to happen in the event of a reaction. On that note, I've tried to access the `tv_embed` using code similar to this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    print("planning to ember.set_field_at(...) here")
    from_new_poll = await new_poll.tv_embed
    from_new_polll = await new_poll.message
    await from_new_polll.edit(embed = from_new_poll)
```

But I get error similar to this:

```
planning to ember.set_field_at(...) here
Ignoring exception in on_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vale/.virtualenvs/discord_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vale/Documents/arcane/e_project-kindling/Discord-Bot/main.py", line 108, in on_reaction_add
    from_new_poll = await new_poll.tv_embed
AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'tv_embed'
```

Could someone please kindly explain what's going on here, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A simple method could be using a dictionary or other data structure, accessible from anywhere, for example:

```py
# after your bot instantiation (or at __init__)
bot = commands.Bot(...)
bot.polls = {}

# In same file commands:
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
  print(bot.polls)

#In cogs:
self.bot.polls
ctx.bot.polls
```

Now in your poll command

```py
msg = await ctx.send(...)
author_polls = bot.polls.setdefault(author, [])
author_polls.append(msg)
```

And finally, in your event handler

```py
msg = reaction.message
polls = bot.polls.get(msg.author)
if polls and msg in polls:
  ... # we know this reaction happened in a message that has a poll
```

In this example i just stored the original message but you could store whatever you need there.

Consider that this is not safe as restarts will clear data and break this. You should use a database and store whatever IDs you want. You could load this and construct the dictionary at startup and just update it with each new poll.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access variables defined in another function, they're only visible **inside** of that function, so not anywhere else. `new_poll.tv_embed` is essentially the same as `any_command.tv_embed`, as the `tv_embed` variable is not visible to the outside world. If you're not aware of this I suggest you look into `scopes` a bit.

If you want to access it, you have to store it somewhere outside of the function (eg. as a variable in your `Cog` or somewhere else in your `.py` file).

I do have to point out that if you're trying to do something like this, there's a bigger issue and the overall design of your code is just off. This is almost **never** the way. In your case, you can access the original embed from the `reaction` parameter and edit it straight away without having to store it anywhere at all.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    # "reaction" has a "message" field that contains a reference to the message that the reaction was placed on
    message = reaction.message
    # A "Message" has a list of all embeds attached to this message, in your case I assume there's only one
    tv_embed = message.embeds[0]
```

Note that the above ^ will crash for messages that don't have any `embeds`, it's just meant as an example to give you an idea here, not a fully-fledged solution. You'll need some `if-statements` here and there to check if you should edit this embed or not, so check if there even *is* an embed to begin with as well. This should be enough to get you going though, and those checks are up to you to write.

For more info, see the API docs for [on_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_remove#discord.on_reaction_add), [discord.Reaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=reaction#discord.Reaction) and [discord.Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message).

Comment: Much thanks, sir, for the detailed answer, looked into `scopes` and `cog` as you suggested, and now it seems it would be best to learn and use `cog` instead of my original approach.

Comment: If this solved your problem remember to accept the answer.